# how to add a secondary navbar to bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following bootstrap navbar on my site.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mi Thai Resturant</a>
   </div>
   <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">other locations</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

What I want to do is when user click other locations I want another horizontal bar to appear underneath with a links including other locations. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: why dont you use bootstraps built in drop down menus for their nav bars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a little jQuery to show/hide the subnav onclick.

Working Example: http://www.bootply.com/iiVhh1BAGm

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mi Thai Resturant</a>
   </div>
   <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" class="subnav-trigger">other locations</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>

<nav id="subnav" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery

```
$( ".subnav-trigger" ).click(function() {
  $( "#subnav" ).toggle();
});
```

CSS

```
#subnav {
 display:none; 
}
```

Comment: This is exactly i was trying to do. Thanks. How can I reduce the gap between two nav bars?

Comment: The .navbar element has a style of margin-bottom:20px; applied to it in bootstrap.css. You can adjust this to affect both navbars, or to leave margin on second, but adjust the first, you should add a unique id to first navbar, then adjust margin-bottom in your CSS using the id.

Comment: should I add another class with to reduce the margin? and use that, like `class=navbar nomargin`

Comment: Class or id, it's up to you. Creating a .nomargin class is okay if you intend to use it on other elements in your document.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got a piece of code that can help you out. Have a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3zh4jxgh/. Make sure the jQuery code in the HTML section go's in the HEAD of your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#main-menu").hover(
      function() {
         $("#submenu").animate({
         height: '+=102' /* add 51 to this number for each li class="text" in the submenu */
      }, '0' 
  );

   $(".text").css({"display": "block"
      }
   );


},

      function() {
         $("#submenu").animate({
         height: '-=102', /* add 51 to this number for each li class="text" in the submenu */
      }, '0'
  );

        $(".text").css({"display": "none"
      }
   );

   }
   );

   });


</script>
```

This is the HTML I used in the Fiddle:

```
<div id="main-menu" onClick="menu()">MENU</div>
<div id="submenu">

    <li class="text">A title</li>
    <li class="text">Another title</li>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#main-menu {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    color:white;
    font-family:helvetica;
    position:relative;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    font-size:18pt;
}

#submenu {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:0px;
    background-color:grey;
}

.text {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    font-family:helvetica;
    display:none;
    color:white;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    font-size:16pt;
    border-bottom:1px solid #434347;
}
```

Small note: in the Fiddle, I had to add the jQuery to the HTML file in order to work.